# The package option for Shoes on Linux

Tags: linux, shoes

The `--package` option for Shoes appears to be missing on Linux. 
`./shoes.run --package`

Any ideas where it is?

Comment: I got an answer yesterday (it's gone now) telling me that I have to use --package with shoes itself, not the shoes.run downloaded from shoooes.net. 

Do I have to build shoes from source to get this executable??

Answer (score 1):

try "shoes2.run -- --package"

that works for me, but only with the download from shoooes.net - not with the version from ubuntu repos :S